# Using UIImageView's with [UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets] in a UITableView causes lag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, lag

Here is the code I'm using to generate the UITableViewCell. I'm testing in iOS6/iOS7. If I remove the code about the UIImageView the UITableView scrolls just fine. But with the UIImageView it lags and spasms. I'm looking for some solution to fix the lagging. Thank you in advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BubbleCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UILabel *label;
        UIImageView *bubbleLeft;
        UIImageView *bubbleRight;

        if(cell == nil)
        {
        cell = [[
    UITableViewCell
    alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

            label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            label.tag = 1;

            NSString *fileLeft = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chatBubbleGray.png" ofType:nil];
            NSString *fileRight = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chatBubbleBlue.png" ofType:nil];

    UIImage
    *bubbleImageLeft = [[
    UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileLeft] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 22, 20, 22)];

    UIImage
    *bubbleImageRight = [[
    UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileRight] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 22, 20, 22)];

            bubbleLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
            [bubbleLeft setImage:bubbleImageLeft];
            bubbleLeft.tag=2;
            bubbleRight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320 - 20, 10, 10, 10)];
            [bubbleRight setImage:bubbleImageRight];
            bubbleRight.tag=3;

            [cell addSubview:bubbleLeft];
            [cell addSubview:bubbleRight];
            [cell addSubview:label];

        }else{
            label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            bubbleLeft = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            bubbleRight = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        }


    // set frame to largest size you want

        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.
    backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.
    text
    = [[[
    currentDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"string"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];

        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];

        if (indexPath.row%2==0) {
            bubbleRight.hidden = YES;
            bubbleLeft.hidden = NO;
            bubbleLeft.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, expectedLabelSize.width+20, expectedLabelSize.height+20);

            label.frame = CGRectMake(
                                     20, 20,
                                     expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);

        }else{
            bubbleLeft.hidden = YES;
            bubbleRight.hidden = NO;

            bubbleRight.frame = CGRectMake(320 - expectedLabelSize.width - 30, 10, expectedLabelSize.width+20, expectedLabelSize.height+20);

            label.frame = CGRectMake(
                                     320 - expectedLabelSize.width - 20, 20,
                                     expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);
        }



    // Configure the cell...

        return cell;
    }
```

***EDIT:***

Further reviewing the code showed that the lagging is actually caused by this piece of code:
`bubbleLeft.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, expectedLabelSize.width+20, expectedLabelSize.height+20);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that resizableImage was causing the lags as I have stated before. The problem was that I was trying to use this code:

`UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileLeft] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 22, 20, 22)];`

for an image that was

`47x36`.

That means that my caps was going negative flipping the stretchable part causing lag. As a further information the best performance from `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` can be achieved by leaving a `1px x 1px` stretchable area for resizing.

Comment: so what were the UIEdgeInset values that you used for this?

Comment: it would be 17,23,17,23

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing you can do is to create your `UIImages` using `imageNamed:` rather than `imageWithContentsOfFile:`.  `imageNamed:` will typically only load the image from disk one and then cache it, while `imageWithContentsOfFile:` will go out to the disk **every** time.

If that does not get you the performance you are looking for, you might have to move the image loading process to a different thread of execution.

Comment: And also the image can be loaded once, since is the same image, maybe in a `setup` method.

Comment: The images are loaded inly 1 time when the first cells are created. Then they are reused as the cells are reused. Also I have just tried running the code again using `imageNamed:`. But the result is still the same. I have debugged the code again to see that the problem is actually caused by `bubbleLeft.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, expectedLabelSize.width+20, expectedLabelSize.height+20);`

Comment: Alternatively, you could also have several different custom table view cells associated with different reuse identifiers in your storyboard/xib so you wouldn't have to be hiding/showing and adjusting the frames of your table view cells as they are created.